# JS: how to change out variable value from inside extracted inner function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function as follows below where I have a `on` event listener on my video.js player.

```
function mainFunction(document, options, player, win, config) {
    
    let durationTime;

    player.on('ready', () => {

       stylePlayer(document, options);
       reportProgress(player);
       playerControls(player, win);
       durationTime = setInterval(setTime, 1000, playlistUrl);

       postMessage({
           type: 'message_sent',
       });
    })
   
   player.on('ended', () => {

       clearInterval(durationTime);
   })
}
```

I now have a different player that is may or may not appear so I conditionally add a different event listener like this:

```
function mainFunction(document, options, player, win, config) {
        
    let durationTime;

    if (config.showOther) {

        player.getAMSPlayer().addEventListener('Ready', () => {
            addSpecialPlayerStyles()                

            stylePlayer(document, options);
            reportProgress(player);
            playerControls(player, win);
            durationTime = setInterval(setTime, 1000, 'yes');
    
            postMessage({
                type: 'message_sent',
            });
        })
    } else {

        player.on('ready', () => {
           
            stylePlayer(document, options);
            reportProgress(player);
            playerControls(player, win);
            durationTime = setInterval(setTime, 1000, 'yes');
    
            postMessage({
                type: 'message_sent',
            });
        })
    }

    player.on('ended', () => {
        clearInterval(durationTime);
    })
}
```

I realize this is verbose and I tried extracting the logic into a single function, `doNormalStuff`, like:

```
function doNormalStuff(document, options, player, win) {
    stylePlayer(document, options);
    reportProgress(player);
    playerControls(player, win);
    durationTime = setInterval(setTime, 1000, 'yes');

    postMessage({
        type: 'message_sent',
    });
}

function mainFunction(document, options, player, win, config) {
        
    let durationTime;

    if (config.showOther) {
            player.getAMSPlayer().addEventListener('Ready', () => {
            addSpecialPlayerStyles()

            doNormalStuff(document, options, player, win, durationTime);
        });
    else {
        player.on('ready', () => {
            doNormalStuff(document, options, player, win, durationTime);
        })
    }
}
```

but the issue is `durationTime` is a variable set in `mainFunction`.  How can I change the value of that if I extract the inner logic into a new function?
When the `ended` event listener is fired, `clearInterval(durationTime);` and `durationTime` is `undefined` since I set it inside the new function.

Comment: Have you tried returning `durationTime` from `doNormalStuff` and setting it in `mainFunction`?

Comment: @TylerZeller not sure what you mean?  If I `return durationTime` at the end of `doNormalStuff()`, how would I use it inside `mainFunction()`

Comment: Once you `return durationTime` in `mainFunction` you can then set `durationTime = doNormalStuff(...)`, no?

Answer (score 1):

You could use OOP and structure your code as methods of a class/object instance that have access to the same shared `this` properties.

Using ES5 prototype for compatibility:

```js
var PlayerControl = function(document, options, player, win, config) {
    this.document = document;
    this.options = options;
    this.player = player;
    this.win = win;
    this.config = config;
    return this;
};

PlayerControl.prototype.doNormalStuff = function() {
    stylePlayer(this.document, this.options);
    reportProgress(this.player);
    playerControls(this.player, this.win);
    this.durationTime = setInterval(setTime, 1000, 'yes');

    postMessage({
        type: 'message_sent',
    });
}

PlayerControl.prototype.mainFunction = function() {
    if (this.config.showOther) {
            this.player.getAMSPlayer().addEventListener('Ready', () => {
            addSpecialPlayerStyles()
            this.doNormalStuff();
        });
    } else {
        this.player.on('ready', () => {
            this.doNormalStuff();
        })
    }

    this.player.on('ended', () => {
        clearInterval(this.durationTime);
    })
}

var plControl = new PlayerControl(...YourArgs);
plControl.mainFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass parameter as `reference type`. So you have to define object that has `durationTime` property and send it to another function.

Here is small sample:

```js
 b();

 function b() {
     let object = { durationTime: 0 };
     alert("initial value of durationTime is: " + object.durationTime)

     a(object);

     alert("change value of durationTime by another method to : " + object.durationTime)
 }

 function a (obj) {
     obj.durationTime = 10;
 }
```